# Rails - Adding a CSS Class to Link_to_(my javascript function)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Following Railscasts #197, would anyone know how to add a class to the link_to that's calling a js function?

```
<%= link_to_add_fields "Add Recipient", f, :recipients %>
```

_

```
function add_fields(link, association, content) {
        var new_id = new Date().getTime();
        var regexp = new RegExp("new_" + association, "g");
        $(link).parent().before(content.replace(regexp, new_id));
}
```

I've tried a lot of different things but haven't found anything that worked.  Like, I assume it should be something like:

```
<%= link_to_add_fields "Add Recipient", {f, :recipients}, :class => "button_add" %>
```

which would produce (with or without brackets around the two object being passed to the function:

```
undefined method `object' for #<Hash:0xaa8c320>
```

Ruby 1.8.7 / Rails 2.3.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would extend method with css_class parameter

```
module ApplicationHelper

    def link_to_add_fields(name, f, association, css_class)
        new_object = f.object.class.reflect_on_association(association).klass.new
        fields = f.fields_for(association, new_object, :child_index => "new_#{association}") do |builder|
            render(association.to_s.singularize + "_fields", :f => builder)
        end
        link_to_function(name, "add_fields(this, \"#{association}\", \"#{escape_javascript(fields)}\")", :class => css_class)
    end
end
```

then i assume you can call the helper method as follow

```
<%= link_to_add_fields "Add Recipient", f, :recipients, "button_add" %>
```

I have not tried that, but this resource speak clearly

[apidock link_to_function](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/JavaScriptHelper/link_to_function)